# Non case-sensitive sorting in dojo dgrid

Tags: javascript, dojo, dgrid

Is it possible to sort without case-sensitivity?

For instance, sorts by default show up like this:

```
Awesomeman
adam
beyonce
```

but, I'd like to sort like:

```
adam
Awesomeman
beyonce
```

Is it possible to override the sensitivity easily? From what I can tell the grid inherits from `OnDemandGrid` and `OnDemandList`, which both inherit from `Grid` and `List`. For my store, I am using `Memory` wrapped in `Observable`.

As of now, I'm trying to overwrite `_setSort` in `List.js`, however that's not working. Anyone out there familiar with these frameworks?

Comment: Are you using `dojo/store/Memory` or something else?  I ask since Memory would sort capital letters first, not last, and the response may depend on the store implementation.

Comment: I'm a `Memory` wrapped in `Observerable` -- maybe I've gotten it reverse (capital before lowercase). Could I customize in the store itself?

Comment: Yes just double checked -- The capital letters do come first. I will update the question!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are potentially 2 ways of solving this:

- On the grid end, by handling and canceling the `dgrid-sort` event
- On the store end, by extending `query` to coerce `sort` into doing what you want (preferred)

First, the `dgrid-sort` version:

```
grid.on('dgrid-sort', function (event) {
    // Cancel the event to prevent dgrid's default behavior which simply
    // passes the sort criterion through to the store and updates the UI
    event.preventDefault();
    // sort is an array as expected by the store API, but dgrid's UI only sorts one field at a time
    var sort = event.sort[0];
    grid.set('sort', function (a, b) {
        var aValue = a[sort.attribute].toLowerCase();
        var bValue = b[sort.attribute].toLowerCase();
        if (aValue === bValue) {
            return 0;
        }
        var result = aValue > bValue ? 1 : -1;
        return result * (sort.descending ? -1 : 1);
    });
    // Since we're canceling the event, we need to update the UI ourselves;
    // the `true` tells it to also update dgrid's internal representation
    // of the sort setting, so that toggling between asc/desc will still work
    grid.updateSortArrow(event.sort, true);
});
```

While this works for handling when the user clicks in header cells, it will not take effect for programmatic `set('sort')` calls, or the initial setting of `sort` in the object passed to the Grid constructor, which could be problematic.

Since sorting is ultimately a store concern, addressing it on the store end is really the preferable solution.  Admittedly `dojo/store/Memory` and namely `dojo/store/util/SimpleQueryEngine` doesn't make this...well...simple...  but one thing to note about `SimpleQueryEngine` is that if you pass a function via `queryOptions.sort` rather than an array, it will be applied verbatim as the sort function to use.

This means we can take the incoming `sort` array that dgrid will set, write our own version of `SimpleQueryEngine`'s default sort function while also accounting for case-insensitivity, and store that in `queryOptions.sort` for the inherited call:

```
var CIMemory = declare(Memory, {
    query: function (query, queryOptions) {
        var sort = queryOptions && queryOptions.sort;
        if (sort) {
            // Replace sort array with a function equivalent that performs
            // case-insensitive sorting
            queryOptions.sort = function (a, b) {
                for (var i = 0; i < sort.length; i++) {
                    var aValue = a[sort[i].attribute].toLowerCase();
                    var bValue = b[sort[i].attribute].toLowerCase();
                    if (aValue !== bValue) {
                        var result = aValue > bValue ? 1 : -1;
                        return result * (sort[i].descending ? -1 : 1);
                    }
                }
                return 0;
            }
        }
        return this.inherited(arguments);
    }
});
```

Using this in place of `dojo/store/Memory` will cause all sorts to be case-insensitive.

Note that I took a couple of shortcuts over `SimpleQueryEngine`'s `sort` function (checking for null/undefined and coercing values to primitives).  Alter the sort function as necessary if you need to worry about either of those things.

Comment: Thanks @KenFranqueiro! Will try to implement and keep this updated. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, for lack of a better solution, I found that I had to create a custom version of dojo's `SimpleQueryEngine`, adding `.toLowerCase()` on both of the values [here](https://github.com/dojo/dojo/blob/master/store/util/SimpleQueryEngine.js#L92). The reason it couldn't be simply changed was because it happens inside of an internal function (inside of another function) so it was easier to make another version entirely.

Then, when creating `Memory`, passing in the query engine like so:

```
new Memory({ queryEngine : customEngine });
```

and it seems to work. If there's a cleaner solution please share bc I hate this one :)

Comment: Since you answered my comment, I will work up an answer later tonight.  There are potentially a couple of ways to skin this cat that aren't as copypaste-ish as that, though they still might not be as straightforward as one would like.

Comment: @KenFranqueiro That'd be amazing. Thank you for your help. Even so, if you're interested in refactoring the SimpleQueryEngine to make the inner functions more re-writeable let me know in general and i'll put out a PR