# dgrid- case insensitive column sorting

Tags: javascript, sorting, dgrid

[Non case-sensitive sorting in dojo dgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26783489/non-case-sensitive-sorting-in-dojo-dgrid)

answer posted by @https://stackoverflow.com/users/237950/ken-franqueiro

```
grid.on('dgrid-sort', function (event) {
    // Cancel the event to prevent dgrid's default behavior which simply
    // passes the sort criterion through to the store and updates the UI
    event.preventDefault();
    // sort is an array as expected by the store API, but dgrid's UI only sorts one field at a time
    var sort = event.sort[0];
    grid.set('sort', function (a, b) {
        var aValue = a[sort.attribute].toLowerCase();
        var bValue = b[sort.attribute].toLowerCase();
        if (aValue === bValue) {
            return 0;
        }
        var result = aValue > bValue ? 1 : -1;
        return result * (sort.descending ? -1 : 1);
    });
    // Since we're canceling the event, we need to update the UI ourselves;
    // the `true` tells it to also update dgrid's internal representation
    // of the sort setting, so that toggling between asc/desc will still work
    grid.updateSortArrow(event.sort, true);
});
```

What are the values of a and b variables?
In my case I don't want to touch the library file, my event argument has the complete details of the grid, so I wanted to sort the data present in event argument and update the grid, how should I modify the above code?